# PDO object is not initialized, constructor was not called in

Tags: php, sql, pdo, constructor, connection

I pretty new using PHP with PDO and I'm trying to create a connection but I'm getting this error.

> PDO object is not initialized, constructor was not called.

The code of my connection is this, inspired from [this example](https://pastebin.com/w7zgjjag) I saw:

```
    class Connection extends PDO {
    private $type = 'mysql|mysqli';
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $database =  'xxxxx';
    private $user = 'xxxx';
    private $pass = 'xxxx';

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            parent::__construct($this->type . ':host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->database, $this->user, $this->pass);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "something";
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using this connection like this

```
function getUser($userID) {
    $connection = new Connection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :userID";
    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
    $query->execute();
    ....
}
```

I would really appreciate any clue. Thanks!

Comment: Is your type really 'mysql|mysqli'? Don't you just mean 'mysql'?

Comment: FWIW extending the PDO class is probably not a great design

Comment: Why are you extending PDO? All you seem to be doing is to hard code your database credentials into the code, which isn't a good idea to start with. Also, don't create a new connection for every query (which it looks like you're doing). You should create a connection once and reuse that connection through out the request. If not, you risk of running out of connections if you do multiple queries in a request and have a few simultaneous users.

Comment: You didn't update your question, you changed it. Please don't do that. If you have a new question, then create a new question. Sorry, but this is how stack overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this |mysqli.

```
class Connection extends PDO {
private $type = 'mysql';
private $host = 'localhost';
private $database =  'xxxxx';
private $user = 'xxxx';
private $pass = 'xxxx';

public function __construct() {
    try {
        parent::__construct($this->type . ':host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->database, $this->user, $this->pass);
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "something";
    }
}
```